# Deleted apps in iTunes. Can I transfer them from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, ios-appstore

I've deleted apps from my iTunes.

Can I transfer them somehow from my iPhone? Or I should re-download them one by one?

When I try to sync my iPhone, iTunes want's to delete apps…

Comment: When you sync your iPhone it should prompt you to transfer the purchases. If it doesn't, the easiest way is probably to download them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the iPhone in the list on the left there should be an option to transfer purchases. Click that and it should transfer all your apps to your computer.